# Use awk to modify lines with specific keys

Tags: unix, awk

I have a main file that includes a series of data lines whose ID's are stored in the second column. There is another key file that contains specific IDs and I would like to comment (put $) the records with those ID's in the main file and leave the rest. I have written the below script, it puts the comment but repeats the non-keyed items. Can you please help debug the awk command?

key_file:

```
10  
20  
30
```

main_file:

```
PSHELL      10  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      20  136513    2.0                  
PSHELL      30  13571     1.7
```

Current output:

```
PSHELL      10  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      10  136514    0.7                
$PSHELL     10  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      20  136513    2.0                
$PSHELL     20  136513    2.0                
PSHELL      20  136513    2.0                
$PSHELL     30  13571     1.7   
PSHELL      30  13571     1.7   
PSHELL      30  13571     1.7
```

Desired output

```
$PSHELL      10  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
$PSHELL      20  136513    2.0                
$PSHELL      30  13571     1.7
```

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for (i in a) if (index($2, i)) {print "$"$0 > "out_file"} else {print $0 > "out_file"}}' key_file main_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {key[$1]; next} $2 in key {$0 = "$" $0} 1' keyfile mainfile
$PSHELL      10  136514    0.7
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7
$PSHELL      20  136513    2.0
$PSHELL      30  13571     1.7
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava ! this is a smart solution. one question : what is the role of 1 just before the single quote ? Also, can I output this to a file?

Comment: `1` is just a shortcut to print each record. To redirect to a file use: `awk 'FNR == NR {key[$1]; next} $2 in key {$0 = "$" $0} 1' keyfile mainfile > output`

Comment: One more question : how can I modify the code to only print first 2 columns (instead of entire record)?

Comment: Thanks, but this updates all the records. I want to print the first 2 columns only for the records that match the key, for the rest, the entire record shall be printed.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear in my question. In the output file (in above command), I would like to print: all the columns for non-matching records and first 2 columns for the matching records. Is it possible to modify the existing command to fulfill this purpose?

Comment: Sure, here is the new posting - thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459055/using-awk-to-print-range-of-columns-for-matching-keys

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer with explanation