# Using awk to print range of columns for matching keys

Tags: shell, unix, awk

this seems to have an easy solution, but I am stuck. I would like to look up the second column of a main file in a key file, and for any matched key, print only the first 2 columns, but the entire record for the rest. I have a working script but that prints the entire line for the matched keys. Can you please help?

```
awk 'FNR == NR {key[$1]; next} $2 in key {print $1,$2}' keyfile mainfile > outfile
```

mainfile:

```
PSHELL      10  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      20  136513    2.0                  
PSHELL      30  13571     1.7
```

keyfile:

```
10
30
```

outfile:

```
PSHELL      10                
PSHELL      15  136514    0.7                
PSHELL      20  136513    2.0                  
PSHELL      30
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$0 = "$" $0`?

Comment: I updated the script... this one does print the 2 columns for the matched keys but skips the non-matched lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {key[$1]; next} $2 in key {print $1,$2;next} 1' keyfile mainfile
```

The last `1` denotes an empty block whose default behavior is to print the whole line.
And combined with the `next` in the preceding block, acts as a kind of `if else` switch.

Comment: Thank you ! very interesting approach

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {key[$1]; next} {print ($2 in key ? $1 OFS $2 : $0)}' keyfile mainfile | column -t > outfile

cat outfile

PSHELL  10
PSHELL  15  136514  0.7
PSHELL  20  136513  2.0
PSHELL  30
```

Here:

- Used ternary operation to print `$1 OFS $2` when we find `$2` in `key` array otherwise we print `$0`.
- used `column -t` for tabular outut

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more approach for doing same operation. Assuming you don't care of order of output lines, then following may help you too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$2]=$1 OFS $2
  arr2[$2]=$0
  next
}
($1 in arr1){
  print arr1[$1]
  arr3[$1]
}
END{
  for(key in arr2){
    if(!(key in arr3)){
      print arr2[key]
    }
  }
}
' mainfile keyfile
```